# Emulated environments -- hardware clock ticking a lot faster than 18.2 times per second?

Tags: assembly, virtual-machine, clock, bios, bochs

I'm writing an assembly game that uses the real-time, hardware BIOS clock (that ticks 18.2 times per second) for delays. I'm debugging the program with BOCHS and I've also tested it with VirtualBox.

Now, the problem is that in these virtual environments, the hardware clock is way too fast (faster than 18.2 times per second, for sure). If I set a delay for 1 second, BOCHS & VirtualBox complete that delay ~10 times sooner than they're supposed to. On a real computer, the delay is exactly 1 second (as it should be).

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765480/interrupt-0x15-function-0x86-bios-wait-runs-far-slower-on-real-hardware-than-o?) a couple days ago, in which I falsely assumed that my real laptop BIOS was running too fast: well, it's actually the other way around.

BIOS = exact timing
Emulated = way too fast timing

There are no problems with my actual code (I'm simply using the int 15h, ah = 86h) BIOS WAIT service that in turn accesses the clock. So...

I'm wondering how it's even possible that emulated environments can afford to have such a high tick rate of their "real-time" clock. Wouldn't that mess up other programs? And most importantly, how can one "tune" the clock in BOCHS, for example? Can I make the emulated clock accurate, so that I don't have to restart my laptop everytime I want to test my game?

PS: I've also noticed that the "_" cursor blinks faster than one would expect it to in BOCHS

Comment: In Bochs what if you change the line in your bochs configuration file so that it attempts to use `realtime`. Change the `clock:` line to something like `clock: sync=realtime, time0=local, rtc_sync=0`

Comment: Ok, that fixes the timing (it takes longer now) but everything else runs extremely slow too. Going through the bochs bios startup takes a couple seconds and drawing to vram takes even longer. Looks like the `clock:` slows everything down, not the 18.2-second tick rate specifically

Comment: it is generally not expected to have emulated environments meet this kind of timing.  depends on how deep the emulation is.  since pipelines, caches, etc you cannot accurately determine the execution time of an instruction or much less many.  older say 6502 emulators could count ticks roughly this instruction was 3 clocks if the branch was taken add another.  Then every N clocks you could say was some unit of time and then fire an interrupt or have a clock peripheral count one second, etc.  I cant see that any of that is going on here.  they will have some scheme

Comment: to say have well known timed interrupts happen based on real time and the emulated program hopefully uses those to say do frame rate updates and you work off of that.  but that still isnt perfect as it depends partly on the programs...basically dont expect time to be accurate, now saying that if you are using a system/bios function that is ideally tied to a wall clock time/tick then the emulator should be able to wait that many ticks. assuming it doesnt emulate too fast.

Comment: http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/bochsrc.html says that you can set the `ips` config variable to the average instructions-per-second that your machine can actually emulate, and that will affect some timing things.  I don't know BOCHS well, but IDK if there's an option to have timers based on wall-clock real time, but still emulate as fast as possible (so the emulated CPU frequency is variable).

Comment: I understand that timing in emulators isn't meant to be accurate, but I'd never have imaged it'd be SO inaccurate (~10times too fast). I'll try changing around the `ips` config variables and see how that works out, thanks for the tip

Comment: Multiply the IPS value by 10 and see what happens

Comment: Turns out I didn't have a `cpu:` line in my bochsrc.txt. I added `cpu: model=core2_penryn_t9600, count=1, ips=30000000, reset_on_triple_fault=1, ignore_bad_msrs=1` (found [here](https://github.com/viking/pure64-example/blob/master/.bochsrc)). After tweaking the ips number I finally got it to work decently. Thanks everyone.